# Revert Object.defineProperty getter to original state, that is normal constant property

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I am trying to implement status effects in a way so that there will be little or no `if` cases in the game program, that is, the effects should apply themselves on the objects.

I created a simple test case, the basic skeleton of my plan:

```
// This can represent a game object - player or monster
var test = {damage: 20};
// For the sake of simplicity, I just define
// EffectMissfortune without inheriting other classes
function EffectMissfortune() {

}
/**
 * Applies effect on an object, altering it's properties 
 * until remove is called **/
EffectMissfortune.prototype.apply = function(obj) {
  // Remember oridinal damage
  obj._damage = obj.damage;
  // Define property getter
  Object.defineProperty(obj, "damage", {
    // Has about 40% chance to return 50% damage
    get: function() {
      if(Math.random()<0.4) {
        return this._damage/2; 
      }
      else
        return this._damage;
    },
    // This should allow me to overwrite this, right?
    configurable: true
  });
}
/**
 * Removes anything that was set aby `apply` method**/
EffectMissfortune.prototype.remove = function(obj) {
  obj.damage = obj._damage;
}
```

I just wrote that in Firebug console and I omitted lot's of stuff like remembering applied status effects and so on. The important thing is that my `.remove` method doesn't work:

```
// Test:
console.log("No effect: ");
console.log(test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage);
// Apply effect
var effect = new EffectMissfortune();
effect.apply(test);
console.log("Missfortune: ");
console.log(test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage);
effect.remove(test);
// Effect removed?
console.log("No effect: ");
console.log(test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage, test.damage);
```

And output:

```
No effect: 
20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20
Missfortune: 
20 10 10 10 10 10 20 10
No effect: 
10 10 20 20 10 20 20 20
```

So the first simple question is:

- How to remove **anything** that was set by last `Object.defineProperty` call?

The second harder one is:

- If I was to apply multiple effects at a time, I'd like to chain anything they defined. In that case, can I **retrieve** current `Object.defineSettings` (get, set, configurable, enumerable and property actual value) before calling my own `Object.defineProperty`? Something like `Object.getPropertySettings`?

Comment: I  would really recommend not to use a getter (that dynamically overwrites a property), but to use an array of effects which is evaluated through a hook in `obj.getDamage()`.

Comment: @Bergi is right - I'm going to update my answer

Comment: @Bergi I was not planning to make the model as simple as described in question, but I'll definitelly base it on `Object.defineProperty`. If I wanted to make methods like `.getDamage` I'd write a game in Java, but I'm not.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but still you should try not to re-define the methods (or accessor properties, which is the same in that regard). Give the object a hook, like an array to insert effects, that is contacted for computing damage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the `writable` property to `true` if you want to be able to override the property value with a simple assignment (`=`). The `configurable` property will allow the property to be altered by a subsequent call to `Object.defineProperty()` but not by assignment.

*edit* — **However**, a property cannot be both `writable` *and* have accessor methods. In this case, then, you can remove the value with another `.defineProperty()` call:

```
EffectMissfortune.prototype.remove = function(obj) {
  Object.defineProperty(obj, "damage", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: obj._damage
  });
}
```

As to your second question, you can get a list of the properties with `Object.keys()` and then use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` for each property.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.

Comment: Actually, `writable` should not affect anything if he is using a getter; assignment will just lead to a "no setter defined" exception.